# What META TAG i should put to deindex whole indexed pages

Tags: tags, meta

What META TAG i should put to deindex whole indexed pages and leave only homepage indexed ?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

**All bots (that honor this meta tag):**

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex">
```

**Only Google:**

```
<meta name="googlebot" content="noindex">
```

Add these to these to the `<head>` section of the pages that you do not want indexed.  In your case, leave it off of your home page.

**Reference**: [Using meta tags to block access to your site](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93710)

Comment: Then change that, or (1) meta tags are not what you want and (2) you should have specified your lack of distinct control over the header in your question.